# How to generate array of size M that only contains elements from provided list?

Tags: python, arrays

What am I trying to achieve?

- I am trying to generate array of size `M`, but elements of that array can only be ones that can be find within of provided list.

My Python code:

```
import random
def generisanjevol1(nekalista):
 return random.choice(nekalista)


listaslova=['A','B','C','D','E']

for x in range(4):
 lista=[generisanjevol1(listaslova)]

print(lista)
```

Output:

```
['E']
```

As shown, in the output that I am getting there's only one element and not 4 (I expected to be 4, because of for loop)

Example of wanted Output:

```
['B', 'E', 'A', 'C']
```

Deeper explanation of what I am trying to achieve:

I have 1 array of 5 strings and I am trying to pass that array into function (generisanjevol1) and there I should generate array of size **M** (generated by random.choice() function but that array should be generated only from these 5 strings which are in array (listaslova) )
Can anyone help me how to do that exactly and how can I save multiple 'data' into one array ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to generate array of size `M` that has elements only from supplied list. You can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices) with `k=` parameter:

```
import random

M = 4

def generisanjevol1(nekalista, m):
    return random.choices(nekalista, k=m)

listaslova=['A','B','C','D','E']

lista=generisanjevol1(listaslova, M)
print(lista)
```

Prints (for example):

```
['A', 'E', 'C', 'E']
```